# Получение MCC, MNC, LAC, CID из js

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

Необходимо определить посетителя сайта по ближайшим телефонным вышкам от него, 
для этого необходимо определить его:

1. Mobile country code (**MCC**)
2. Mobile network code (**MNC**)
3. Location area code (**LNC**)
4. CellID (**CID**)

Можно ли и если да то как это можно реализовать на js?

P.S. Я понимаю что у js нет прямого доступа к железу, однако может есть какие-либо обходы?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько знаю, напрямую с сайта получить нельзя, только если будете использовать приложение на каком-нибудь фреймворке (например, PhoneGap). Как вариант подгрузить базы ip-адресов мобильных операторов связи и по ним смотреть кто ходил на сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Это скорее всего невозможно.

Если бы Вы знали CID то остальное можете посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686888/finding-location-using-mcc-mnc-lac-and-cell-id). А CID получить с JS невозможно.

Вам нужно чтобы приложение было установлено на телефоне.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению на ответы уделили недостаточное кол-во времени и как вследствие ответили поверхностно, вопрос не раскрыт, ответ не получил :(
(скорее всего вопрос слишком специфический и стоило добавить тег android в описание).

**Что нашел:** 
Есть возможность выполнить произвольный java код и как вследствие найти необходимые параметры (MCC, MNC) через компонент WebView посредством вызова java функции из js.

Подробнее о WebView можно прочитать [тут](https://habr.com/company/mailru/blog/262167/).
На hacker немного раскрывают эксплотацию возможности, [тут](https://xakep.ru/2014/09/10/obzor-eksplojtov-3/).

Прошу дополнять ответ в комментарии.